# Couldn't locate an element in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The functionality goes like this:

if you search a name, search results will be displayed in rows. In those results,  one should be selected whose status is "Active". To select one, you should click on the link which is placed at the start of the row. The choice is based on the status.

So I tried to traverse from the status "Active" to the link with the text "Name goes here" and got `NoSuchElementException`.

The code is:

```
<tr height="20" class="evenListRowS1">

<td scope="row" align="left" valign="top" class="evenListRowS1" bgcolor="">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="send_back('Users','b559b4f3-20ee-9bb0-320d-5a4f630dea17');">Name goes here</a>
</td>

<td scope="row" align="left" valign="top" class="evenListRowS1" bgcolor="">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="send_back('Users','b559b4f3-20ee-9bb0-320d-5a4f630dea17');">email</a>
</td>

<td scope="row" align="left" valign="top" class="evenListRowS1" bgcolor="">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="send_back('Users','b559b4f3-20ee-9bb0-320d-5a4f630dea17');">position</a>
</td>

<td scope="row" align="left" valign="top" class="evenListRowS1" bgcolor="">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="send_back('Users','b559b4f3-20ee-9bb0-320d-5a4f630dea17');">Solutions - CRM Practice</a>
</td>

<td scope="row" align="left" valign="top" class="evenListRowS1" bgcolor="">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="send_back('Users','daac0d91-4481-2204-9b62-580600287265');">Mishra</a>
</td>

<td scope="row" align="left" valign="top" class="evenListRowS1" bgcolor="">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="send_back('Users','b559b4f3-20ee-9bb0-320d-5a4f630dea17');">email-address</a>
</td>

<td scope="row" align="left" valign="top" class="evenListRowS1" bgcolor="">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="send_back('Users','b559b4f3-20ee-9bb0-320d-5a4f630dea17');">+1 62900*2813</a>
</td>

<td scope="row" align="left" valign="top" class="evenListRowS1" bgcolor="">
Active
</td>

<td scope="row" align="left" valign="top" class="evenListRowS1" bgcolor="">
2018-09-30 02:33 PM
</td>

<td scope="row" align="left" valign="top" class="evenListRowS1" bgcolor="">
<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" class="checkbox">
</td>
</tr>
```

I've tried

```
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//table[@class='list view']/tr[td[8][text()=\"Active\"]/td[1]")).click();
```

but I'm getting NoSuchElementException.

Comment: Which _Selenium Language Binding Art_ are you using? _Java_ / _Python_ / _C#_ / _NodeJS_ ? Your code trials?

Comment: @Newcontributor What is a "Binding Art"?

Comment: I am using java

Comment: Add the tag for Java to your question, if that's the programming language you are using. You still need to add the code you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So essentially you want this:

- Find table

  ```
  //table[@class='list view']
  ```
- Skip anything between table an row, as they are not important anyways:

  ```
  //table[@class='list view']//tr
  ```
- Find row where value of column #8 is `Active` (since you are using filter, it's easier to identify position by filter function here. Also based on your HTML, text in that column also contains new lines, so `text()='Active'` won't match, but `contains` will:

  ```
  <...>/td[position()=8 and contains(text(),'Active')]
  ```
- Get column #1 from the same row. So come back to row scope with `..`, and then choose a different column

  ```
  <...>/td[position()=8 and contains(text(),'Active')]/../td[1]
  ```

A complete xpath is:

```
//table[@class='list view']//tr/td[position()=8 and contains(text(),'Active')]/../td[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using x-path to locate the link you want to click? Something like this might work, but you will need to know how to customize this to make it work in your situation.

```
//table[@id="myTable"]//tr[td[8][text()="Active"]]/td[1]
```

- Find the table with `//table[@id="myTable"]`. Change `id="myTable"` to something that uniquely identifies your table.
- Find the row with `//tr[td[8][text()="Active"]]`. This gives you all of the rows that have "Active" in the 8th column.
- Find the first cell in that row with `/td[1]`
- Find the link in that cell `/a`

Here's an example on https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

`//table[@id="customers"]/tbody/tr[td[2][text()="Maria Anders"]]/td[1]`

That will select the first cell in the first row that has "Maria Anders" in the 2nd column.

Comment: It's not working for me. Still couldn't locate the element.

Comment: //table[@class='list view']/tr[td[8][text()=\"Active\"] this xpath couldn't locate the text "Active".

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket. It should be `//table[@class='list view']/tr[td[8][text()=\"Active\"]]/a`. Sorry. I see that I was missing the bracket in my answer.

Comment: I missed the bracket in the comment. I gave the correct syntax in the script. Still not working.

Comment: Kiril S.'s answer is helpful. I forgot to put double slashes between table and tr. Also, what he said about contains "Active" is how I usually do it. If I were you, I would test finding a cell on the w3schools website and see if you can make that work.